# How do you style a vertex on a Google Maps polygon?

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, styling

I am working with Google Maps API v3 and using it draw polygons. When editing a polygon I would like to indicate if a vertex on the polygon is selected, but I cannot find any options to do so?

How do you style a vertex on a Google Maps polygon?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can be done with the Polygon class, but you could try this:

To "select" a **vertex** (corner point), add a [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) over the vertex and `setVisible(false)`, then bind to mouseover/click to `setVisible(true)`.

To "select" an **edge** (line between to point), add a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) over the edge and `setVisible(false)`, then bind to mouseover/click to `setVisible(true)`.